# Can not find module ../models/category

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My github link will explain better.

https://github.com/AdeolaFaraday/ecommerce

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried a lot of things, I keep wondering how I have written my code correctly and my computer is telling me it is wrong.